# Using nth-child to select an even, and then an odd number of elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm attempting to style list items in this particular order:

1:  White
2:  White
3:  Blue
4:  Blue
5:  Blue
6:  White
7:  White
8:  Blue
9:  Blue
10: Blue
11: White
12: White

The pattern is [1-2] [3-4-5] [6-7] [8-9-10]

My html structure is just a simple list:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Is this pattern possible using css nth-child? If so what would my selector look like?

Comment: If you can work about an `ax + b` formula representing the rows you want to match, you can use nth-child.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A shorter code for the same output would be :

```
li {
  color: white;
}
li:nth-child(5n-3),
li:nth-child(5n-4) {
  color: blue;
}
```

```css
li {
  color: white;
}
li:nth-child(5n-4),
li:nth-child(5n-3) {
  color: blue;
}
/** FOR THE DEMO **/

body {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1. text</li>
  <li>2. text</li>
  <li>3. text</li>
  <li>4. text</li>
  <li>5. text</li>
  <li>6. text</li>
  <li>7. text</li>
  <li>8. text</li>
  <li>9. text</li>
  <li>10. text</li>
  <li>11. text</li>
  <li>12. text</li>
</ul>
```

The point is that you don't need to specify which element the white color should apply to but just the ones that need to be Blue as it will override the "default" set white color.

Answer (score 25):

Try:

```
ul li:nth-child(5n),
ul li:nth-child(5n-1),
ul li:nth-child(5n-2) {
color:rgb(0,0,255);
}

ul li:nth-child(5n-3),
ul li:nth-child(5n-4) {
color:rgb(255,255,255);
}
```

Comment: FWIW, given the code provided in the question, the `ul` part of these selectors is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks, @TylerH - I agree with you and I was in two minds as to whether to include the `ul` or not... but decided to do so in the end for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score 9):

Try like so:

```
li:nth-child(5n - 4),
li:nth-child(5n - 3)  {
    color: white;
}

li:nth-child(5n - 2),
li:nth-child(5n - 1),
li:nth-child(5n)  {
    color: blue;
}
```

---

**Live Example**: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vENgbx

Answer (score 5):

*[Thinking aloud]*

- Every 5th item starting from 1 is white
- Every 5th item starting from 2 is white
- Every 5th item starting from 3 is blue
- Every 5th item starting from 4 is blue
- Every 5th item starting from 5 is blue

In order to translate this repeating pattern into `:nth-child(an+b)`, we need five selectors:

- `a` will be 5
- `b` will be from 1 to 5

And the result:

```css
li:nth-child(5n+1),
li:nth-child(5n+2) {
  background-color: #FFF;
}
li:nth-child(5n+3),
li:nth-child(5n+4),
li:nth-child(5n+5) {
  background-color: #00F;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1: White</li>
  <li>2: White</li>
  <li>3: Blue</li>
  <li>4: Blue</li>
  <li>5: Blue</li>
  <li>6: White</li>
  <li>7: White</li>
  <li>8: Blue</li>
  <li>9: Blue</li>
  <li>10: Blue</li>
  <li>11: White</li>
  <li>12: White</li>
</ul>
```